# R: Put Child Elements of an XML node into a data frame, based on the attribute

Tags: r, xml, dataframe

let's say I have a XML-File and i want to write a R Function which takes the attributes I am looking for and searches through an XML-File. The content of the child nodes of these attributes then should be given to a data frame.

```
    <?xml version="1.0"?>
    <catalog>
       <book id="bk101">
          <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
          <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>44.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
          <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
          with XML.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk102">
          <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
          <title>Midnight Rain</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
          <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
          an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
          of the world.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk103">
          <author>Corets, Eva</author>
          <title>Maeve Ascendant</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-11-17</publish_date>
          <description>After the collapse of a nanotechnology 
          society in England, the young survivors lay the 
          foundation for a new society.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk104">
          <author>Corets, Eva</author>
          <title>Oberon's Legacy</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2001-03-10</publish_date>
          <description>In post-apocalypse England, the mysterious 
          agent known only as Oberon helps to create a new life 
          for the inhabitants of London. Sequel to Maeve 
          Ascendant.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk105">
          <author>Corets, Eva</author>
          <title>The Sundered Grail</title>
          <genre>Fantasy</genre>
          <price>5.95</price>
          <publish_date>2001-09-10</publish_date>
          <description>The two daughters of Maeve, half-sisters, 
          battle one another for control of England. Sequel to 
          Oberon's Legacy.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk106">
          <author>Randall, Cynthia</author>
          <title>Lover Birds</title>
          <genre>Romance</genre>
          <price>4.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-09-02</publish_date>
          <description>When Carla meets Paul at an ornithology 
          conference, tempers fly as feathers get ruffled.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk107">
          <author>Thurman, Paula</author>
          <title>Splish Splash</title>
          <genre>Romance</genre>
          <price>4.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
          <description>A deep sea diver finds true love twenty 
          thousand leagues beneath the sea.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk108">
          <author>Knorr, Stefan</author>
          <title>Creepy Crawlies</title>
          <genre>Horror</genre>
          <price>4.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-12-06</publish_date>
          <description>An anthology of horror stories about roaches,
          centipedes, scorpions  and other insects.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk109">
          <author>Kress, Peter</author>
          <title>Paradox Lost</title>
          <genre>Science Fiction</genre>
          <price>6.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-11-02</publish_date>
          <description>After an inadvertant trip through a Heisenberg
          Uncertainty Device, James Salway discovers the problems 
          of being quantum.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk110">
          <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
          <title>Microsoft .NET: The Programming Bible</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>36.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-12-09</publish_date>
          <description>Microsoft's .NET initiative is explored in 
          detail in this deep programmer's reference.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk111">
          <author>O'Brien, Tim</author>
          <title>MSXML3: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>36.95</price>
          <publish_date>2000-12-01</publish_date>
          <description>The Microsoft MSXML3 parser is covered in 
          detail, with attention to XML DOM interfaces, XSLT processing, 
          SAX and more.</description>
       </book>
       <book id="bk112">
          <author>Galos, Mike</author>
          <title>Visual Studio 7: A Comprehensive Guide</title>
          <genre>Computer</genre>
          <price>49.95</price>
          <publish_date>2001-04-16</publish_date>
          <description>Microsoft Visual Studio 7 is explored in depth,
          looking at how Visual Basic, Visual C++, C#, and ASP+ are 
          integrated into a comprehensive development 
          environment.</description>
       </book>
    </catalog>
```

so for example if I put in my function bk107, bk111, bk112 i want the subchild nodes with a headline and the attribute as a row description in a data frame.

```
            author           title                 genre      price   publish_date   description
    bk107   Thurman, Paula   Splish Splash         Romance    4.95    2000-11-02     A deep sea diver fin...
    bk111   O'Brien, Tim     MSXML3: A Compr...    Computer   36.95   2000-12-01     The Microsoft MSX...
    bk112   Galos, Mike      Visual St...          Computer   49.95   2001-04-16     Microsoft Visual Stu...
```

I looked up in an book how the XML package for R works, but this right now is way over my head.

Appreciate any help. <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possibility, if you already know the tags you want to retrieve:

```
# Define the XML text
xml.str <- '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer\'s Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>'

# Parse the XML
xml <- XML::xmlInternalTreeParse(xml.str, asText = TRUE)

# Get the book IDs
ids <- XML::xpathSApply(xml, '//book', XML::xmlGetAttr, 'id')

# Retrieve values for each book
books <- data.frame()
for (id in ids) {
    book <- list(id = id)
    for (field in c('author', 'title', 'genre', 'price', 'publish_date')) {
        value <- XML::xpathSApply(xml, paste0('//book[@id="', id, '"]/', field), XML::xmlValue)
        book[[field]] <- value
    }
    books <- rbind(books, book, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
}

# Result
books
```

Comment: Hey, thank you so much. I will try if i can use this for my file and come back to you <3